# Git post receive hook with sudo -u not working for some users

Tags: wordpress, git, bash, sudo

We have a website we're developing with WP-Engine. To simplify the processes I've set up the git repository for the site to automatically push code changes up to the WP-Engine staging area, using a Post Receive hook that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash -x  
PUSH_AS_USER="admin"  
sudo -u $PUSH_AS_USER git push wp-engine-staging master
```

I've also made it so that any user in the admin group, can sudo -u admin git, without typing the password (for reference, add the following to /etc/sudoers

```
%admin  ALL=(admin)     NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/git`
```

When I push to the repository, it fires the post commit hook no problem, however for some reason it only works for me. Two other users get the following warning:

```
[username@server repository]$ sudo -u admin git push wp-engine-staging master  
fatal: unable to access '/home/username/.config/git/config': Permission denied
```

The weird thing is, I don't have this file for my user and mine works ok. Additionally, if I create the file for those users, I can't seem to give admin permission to view it, even if I add admin to the users own group, and give read permission to the group in every directory to the file. (ie, /home/username/.config/git/ and the config file itself).

As another example of this weird issue:

```
[daniel@server repository]$ sudo su username  
[username@server repository]$ sudo -u admin git config --global --list  
fatal: unable to access '/home/username/.config/git/config': Permission denied  
[username@server repository]$ exit  
[daniel@server repository]$ sudo -u admin git config --global --list  
user.email=daniel@example.com  
user.name=Daniel  
[daniel@server repository]$ cat /home/daniel/.config/git/config  
cat: /home/daniel/.config/git/config: No such file or directory
```

It's rather messing with our workflow. Any ideas?

Comment: Obviously it has something to do with permissions on `.config` or its sub-directory and/or files, but you already checked the obvious.  So maybe it's the un-obvious, e.g., SELinux?  I gave up on trying to work around SELinux things and turned it off entirely, in various previous-$work-things. :-)

Comment: Good thinking, but in this case we aren't using SELinux.

I think I may be looking at two seperate issues here.
1) Git _might_ not be properly set up for the other users (though they can use git when not switching user).
2) When using sudo -u, it's keeping environment variables belonging to the original user.
Unfortunately I haven't been able to fix either of these issues either. :)

Comment: Any luck on this? I'm still yearning for a fix

Comment: No, we ended up leaving out the hook and doing it manually as necessary.

Comment: Are you sure you are running the same git with the same (global) config for each?  `sudo -u admin which git`